# CSS for No Border Thickness

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables, thickness

I have a table that I built out with `0px` border, and I am trying to get images in each row to fit seamlessly to one another but even though the border does not show there is still a `1px` gap in between the rows. Is there a way to fix this?

```
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
}   

table th, table td { 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
}  

tr { 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: did you try `border: none` on the `tr` element?

Answer (score 2):

Might be that the content inside the table is creating some extra space, and you didn't mention what browser, but be aware that [IE7 doesn't understand border-collapse](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html) so you should add:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

to the table for IE7. Also, there is no reason to apply `border-collapse` to the tr.

Answer (score 1):

I think `border-spacing` is for a table.  Did you try `border: none` for the `tr` element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
img {
   border:none;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
..table rows..
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `display: block` for images?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, I had the cellspacing="0" in the HTML, and tried all your suggestions. None seemed to change the outcome, my only thought now is that I'm working on a Mac and that it is some kind of browser issue. I'll have to test it on a PC and see how it looks.